# Why binding navigational property to dropdown list is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, entity-framework-6

I am filling a `DropDownListFor` in razor mvc. I am trying to fill it from Navigational property but it doesn't work.

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'model' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPhase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InitialsID, (IEnumerable<model.InspectionReport.Initials>) Model.InspectionReport.Initials,
                   "-Select-",
                 new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPhase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

InspectionReport.cs

```
namespace VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities
{
    public class InspectionReport
    {
        //General Details
        public int InspectionReportID { get; set; }
        public short? InitialsID { get; set; }
        public virtual Initials Initials { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Initials.cs

```
public class Initials
{
    public short? InitialsID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(IEnumerable<model.InspectionReport.Initials>) Model.InspectionReport.Initials
```

Unfortunately you can't infer generic parameter type like this - you need to provide either fixed type or interface here instead of using `model.something`. When using generics, your type must be resolvable by compiler at compile-time, so you can't use any dynamic code there, neither a property of an object, nor even `typeof(something)`.

More information on type specification for generics can be found in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters).

In your specific case, you will want to replace this piece of code with something like

```
(IEnumerable<Necessary.Namespaces.Initials>) Model.InspectionReport.Initials
```

, replacing `Necessary.Namespaces` with whatever namespace your `Initials` class lives in.